# My mazda milenia wont rev past 2500 rpm

Tags: electrical, mazda

So I just recently bought a 2000 Mazda Milenia s Millennium edition,and on my first day out with it, I experienced a very unusual problem. After about 20 minutes of driving the car wouldn't rev past 2500 rpm. Even If I would floor the accelerator the car would simply not rev past 2500 rpm. It feels as if the car is being electronically limited to 2500 rpm. After start up, for the first 20 minutes or so, the car drives great I can feel no mechanical issues with the car, but then I out of no where this problem occurs. I am at my wits end with this, so any help or solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, this is the [Mazda limp home mode](http://www.mazdaworld.net/forums/lofiversion/index.php?t3385.html).  If you check that link, two common causes are:

1. Vacuum leaks
2. Bad ABV solenoids

In discussing with your mechanic, I would suggest first having them scan for codes to see what is triggering the limp mode.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like a sensor problem. Most modern engines vary the air-to-fuel ratio automatically based on the engine temperature, and do other complicated tricks like changing the spark timing based on temperature and other factors. If one of your sensors is giving inaccurate readings, especially the coolant temperature sensor, all sorts of things could go wrong, resulting in limited performance.

Two other things to check though: after 20 minutes, if you stop the engine and start it again, does the problem go away, and if so, how long until it comes back? if you're going downhill, can you go past 2500 rpm, or is that a hard limit regardless of how much power is required from the engine?